# Null character in strings

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, unicode, null-terminated

Consider this string:

```
var s = "A\0Z";
```

Its length is 3, as given by `s.length`. Using `console.log` you can see the string isn't cut and that `s[1]` is `""` and `s.charCodeAt(1)` is `0`.

When you alert it in Firefox, you see `AZ`. When you alert it in Chrome/Linux using `alert(s)`, the `\0` terminates the string and you see `A`.

My question is: what **should** browsers and Javascript engines do? Is Chrome buggy here? Is there a document defining what should happen?

*As this is a question about standard, a reference is needed.*

Comment: In the Chrome 23 console I see `AB`.

Comment: @JamesAllardice yes, and if you write console.log(s, s.length, s[0], s[1], s[2]) you see the whole string. The problem in Chrome is when using `alert(s)`.

Comment: @dystroy `alert`s are very much OS dependent, there isn't really a way these could be standardised across browsers

Comment: sure they can. by following the standard. \0 is not a recognized escape character :)

Comment: Do you actually use Chrome on Windows or Linux? Perhaps different *window managers* treat `\0` differently, and you *may* see different results...

Comment: Until now I had only tested it on linux but it seems to work as expected on Chrome/Windows. This might just be a bug of Chrom(ium|e)/linux/gnome...

Comment: alert('A\0Z') in Chrome now shows 'AZ'.  Bug fixed. :)

Comment: @broofa It's not fixed on Chrome or Chromium on Ubuntu (28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.12.04.1).

Comment: Chrome has fixed the issue in Chrome 44/Mac

Comment: Also fixed on Chrome 44 Ubuntu

Comment: @PaulLan - Appears to have broken again in Chrome 47 on El Capitan.

Comment: @JDB I don't reproduce it on Chromium 47.0.2526.73 Ubuntu 15.10 (64-bit) For reference for everybody: [the registered issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164126).

Comment: @DenysSéguret - Perhaps it's just a Mac issue, but you can watch the video I made (attached to my comment on the issue): https://chromium.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=1641260004000&name=Chrome+164126_720.mov&token=ABZ6GAeiAZ5ovLGQaomgco62M5bQAJkyDA%3A1452114410101&id=164126&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAeu5_01Be9aRkIn5K2JOvs1TXNDdA%3A1452114410101

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What the browser *should* do is keep track of the string and its length separately since there are no null terminators present in the standard. (A string is just an object with a length).

What Chrome *seems* to do (I am taking your word for this) is use the standard C string functions which terminate at a \0. To answer one of your questions: Yes this to me constitutes a bug in Chrome's handling of the `alert()` function.

Formally the spec says:

> A string literal is zero or more characters enclosed in single or double quotes. Each character may be represented by an escape sequence. All characters may appear literally in a string literal except for the closing quote character, backslash, carriage return, line separator, paragraph separator, and line feed. Any character may appear in the form of an escape sequence.

Also:

> A string literal stands for a value of the String type. The String value (SV) of the literal is described in terms of character values (CV) contributed by the various parts of the string literal.

And regarding the NUL byte:

> The CV [Character Value] of EscapeSequence :: 0 [lookahead ∉ DecimalDigit] is a <NUL> character (Unicode value 0000).

Therefore, a NUL byte should simply be "yet another character value" and have no special meaning, as opposed to other languages where it might end a SV (String value).

For Reference of (valid) "String Single Character Escape Sequences" have a look at the [ECMAScript Language spec section 7.8.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4). There is a table at the end of the paragraph listing the aforementioned escape sequences.

What someone aiming to write a Javascript engine could probably learn from this: Don't use C/C++ string functions. :)

Comment: not a relevant comment: "If \ is followed by a decimal number n whose first digit is not 0".. which is not the case here, see the edit to my post

Comment: Did you read the whole section? It looks like you only read the "Note"...it has "If i is zero, return the EscapeValue consisting of a <NUL> character (Unicode value 0000)." and "\0 represents the <NUL> character and cannot be followed by a decimal digit.", let alone other general information about escaping...

Comment: Do you mean the pseudocode? Yes i read it. The paragraph adds no new information useful to this question. At least none that i can see since the NUL character is already implicitely covered in the string literal section i referenced. Care to enligthen me why i should put it in my answer?

Comment: OT: Have you reported it as a bug to Chromium or V8? I would like to see it. :)

Comment: What I find strange is how could the Chromium team make such a bug. Managing the 0 seems like the most evident problem when calling C functions... That's why I'm a little hesitant to call it a bug.

Comment: They took care of it in the console class which means the alert() function probably slipped their mind. I haven't looked at their code but imagine something like `sprintf()`(-based) moving the value from a closure to another before creating the UI element of the alert. also `strncpy` should still break at the `\0`.. probably should use `memcpy` there.

Comment: @AlvinWong I entered [issue 164126](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164126)

Comment: Note that I'll wait a little (maybe there will be a comment/reason on the issue I entered) before accepting this answer.

Comment: There still is no progress on this issue. There is no reason to wait more : I accept this answer.

Comment: I don't see anything in the snippets you quoted that gives any indication of how a string value should be displayed as output. All three quotes are about string literals, which is a code syntax matter and pretty much the opposite of any discussion about the `alert()` function. If the Chrome JS engine did not allow strings to contain `\0` _at all_, then that would be another matter, but that is not what is under discussion here. I think this is all moot anyway now, though, because Chrome v34 seems to provide the behavior dystroy is expecting.

Comment: '\000\0\u0000\x00' === '\0\0\0\0'

Comment: @DenysSéguret - I've confirmed that the issue is still present in Chrome 47. Added a comment to the Google issue you linked to.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in Chrome 81.

Answer (score 8):

Javascript treat null character just like any other character, your question is how to display it in cosole or in a alert, it vary in different browsers, no standard about this, so chrome is OK.

Comment: I don’t understand why this was downvoted. Though compact, it was the most correct answer before Nelson’s answer, which says the same in much more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking about a non uniform (across browsers) behaviour of `alert()` method, so it has nothing to do with the Script object and the ECMAscript spec as is, it's about how `alert()` shows an String object.

`alert()` is a method of the `Window` object and ECMAscript does not define it (it only tells the host environment may provide global objects as the window object).

But it happens to be a [**w3c spec that defines `alert()`**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/user-prompts.html#dom-alert) behaviour, unfortunately it's very scarse and doesn't provide any hint about how messages with embedded null characters should be shown.

So this behaviour is, as with any other detail not specified in the spec, left out for the browsers own implementations.

Comment: taken that it is defined how a NUL char in a string literal is to be treated, a redefinition would be redundant, no?

Comment: The cited “w3c spec” itself says: “This is a draft document and may be updated, replaced or obsoleted by other documents at any time. It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress.” Moreover, it only says that the `alert()` method shall “show the given *message* to the user”. It does not specify how control characters shall be interpreted in it. So stopping at NUL, though bad quality, does not violate any specification.