# Null Terminator in Java script

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to ASP.net and JaveScript, so am hoping someone can help me. I am going through someone else's code and essentially have something like this (I know this doesn't make sense as is, but it's just to demonstrate the string):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  function onOK()
  {
      var text = "CanSeeThis\0ChromeSeesThisIEdoesnot";
  }  
</script>
```

So I noticed that the above yields different results from Chrome to IE. In IE the \0 ends the string, in Chrome it does not, so we're getting a very different result for text. I can't work out why this is? Is this not a standard null termination character?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698677/null-character-in-strings). Looks like IE incorrectly treats it as a terminating character, since JavaScript is supposed to treat `\0` as "just another character".

Comment: It is a termination character, but **in C**. Browsers should NOT treat it as such.

Comment: Thanks all, that makes sense, will try work out what's happened here. Why though would someone put text after a \0 in the scenario where it's used as a null terminator as it just get's ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this not a standard null termination character?

Not in JavaScript, no, [JavaScript strings](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4) don't use termination characters. (If an implementation does so under the covers, it must remain under the covers, it must not be apparent when using the strings, as that violates the spec.) `\0` is just another character ([Unicode character 0](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0000)) as far as JavaScript is concerned.

If you see the output getting truncated at that point, it's probably been passed as-is to some layer of the relevant software (IE, Windows) that uses the C convention of null terminating strings. That would arguably be a bug, but I expect if you reported it, it'd have a very low priority for getting fixed. :-)