# How to ignore newline in regexp?

Tags: javascript

How to ignore newline in regexp in Javascript ?

for example:

```
 data = "\
    <test>11\n
    1</test>\n\
    #EXTM3U\n\
 "
 var reg = new RegExp( "\<" + "test" + "\>(.*?)\<\/" + "test" + "\>" )
 var match = data.match(reg)
 console.log(match[1])
```

result: undefined

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript regex over multiple lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You are missing a JS newline character `\` at the end of line 2.**

Also, change regexp to:

```
 var data = "\
    <test>11\n\
    1</test>\n\
    #EXTM3U\n\
 ";
 var reg = new RegExp(/<test>(.|\s)*<\/test>/);
 var match = data.match(reg);
 console.log(match[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/DPc2E/

Answer (score 22):

In JavaScript, there is no flag to tell to `RegExp()` that `.` should match newlines. So, you need to use a workaround e.g. `[\s\S]`.

Your RegExp would then look like this:

```
var reg = new RegExp( "\<" + "test" + "\>([\s\S]*?)\<\/" + "test" + "\>" );
```

Answer (score 6):

By reading this one: [How to use JavaScript regex over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines)

I came with that, which works:

```
var data = "<test>11\n1</test>\n#EXTM3U\n";
reg = /<test>([\s\S]*?)<\/test>/;
var match = data.match(reg);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rpkj2/

Comment: Can confirm this works.

Answer (score 3):

Better you can use `[\s\S]` instead of . for multiline matching.

It is the most common JavaScript idiom for matching everything including newlines. It's easier on the eyes and much more efficient than an alternation-based approach like `(.|\n)`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Got it:

I tried to use this regex in notepad++ But the problem is that it finds the whole text from beginning to end

MyRegex:

```
<hostname-validation>(.|\s)*<\/pathname-validation> (finds everything)
/<hostname-validation>(.|\s)*<\/pathname-validation>/ (finds nothing)
/\<hostname-validation\>([\s\S]*?)\<\/pathname-validation\>/ (finds nothing)
**<hostname-validation>([\s\S]*?)<\/pathname-validation> (my desired result)**
```

The text where I use in:

```
<hostname-validation>www.your-tag-name.com</hostname-validation>
          <pathname-validation>pathname</pathname-validation>   <response-validation nil="true"/>
          <validate-absence type="boolean">false</validate-absence> (...) <hostname-validation>www.your-tag-name.com</hostname-validation>
          <pathname-validation>pathname</pathname-validation>   <response-validation nil="false"/>
          <validate-absence type="boolean">false</validate-absence> (...) <hostname-validation>www.your-tag-name.com</hostname-validation>
          <pathname-validation>pathname</pathname-validation>   <response-validation nil="true"/>
          <validate-absence type="boolean">false</validate-absence> (...)
```