# how to use dotall flag for regex.exec()

Tags: javascript, regex

i want get to string in a multiline string that content any specific character and i want get to between two specific staring.

i used this regex and this work but if content have any character (\r \n \t) not work and get null value.

```
This Wotked
    var regex = new RegExp("\-{2}Head(.*)-{2}\/\Head");      
    var content = "--Head any Code and String --/Head";
    var match = regex.exec(content);
```

This Not Worked

```
var regex = new RegExp("\-{2}Head(.*)-{2}\/\Head");      
var content = "--Head \n any Code \n and String --/Head";
var match = regex.exec(content);
```

i found a regexer(http://www.regexr.com/v1/) and know i should use Dotall for multiline string but i cant use dotall for regex.exec

thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

javascript doesn't support `s` (dotall) modifier. The only workaround is to use a "catch all" class, like `[\s\S]` instead of a dot:

```
regex = new RegExp("\-{2}Head([\\s\\S]*)-{2}\/\Head")
```

Also note that your expression can be written more concisely using a literal:

```
regex = /--Head([\s\S]*)--\/Head/
```

Comment: this is no longer true.

Answer (score 36):

In 2018, with the ECMA2018 standard implemented in some browsers for the time being, JS regex now supports [`s` DOTALL modifier](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-get-regexp.prototype.dotAll):

[Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll#Browser_compatibility)

```js
console.log("foo\r\nbar".match(/.+/s)) // => "foo\r\nbar"
```

Actually, **JS native match-all-characters regex construct** is

```
[^]
```

It means ***match any character that is not nothing***. Other regex flavors would produce a warning or an exception due to an incomplete character class ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/pG1fV6/1)), though it will be totally valid for JavaScript ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/pG1fV6/2)).

The truth is, the `[^]` is not portable, and thus is not recommendable *unless* you want your code to run on JS only.

```
regex = /--Head([^]*)--\/Head/
```

To have the same pattern matching any characters in JS and, say, Java, you need to use a workaround illustrated in the other answers: *use a character class with two opposite shorthand character classes when **portability** is key*: `[\w\W]`, `[\d\D]`, `[\s\S]` (most commonly used).

**NOTE that `[^]` is shorter**.

Comment: Great! it's working. This MUST! be the correct answer. @HapyUser please change the accepted answer to this.

Comment: Prefect, I really find a good answer to my question right here!

Answer (score 2):

Use catch all character class `[\s\S]` which means space or non space

```
var regex = new RegExp("\-{2}Head([\s\S]*)-{2}\/\Head","m");      
var content = "--Head \n any Code \n and String --/Head";
var match = regex.exec(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `s` modifier, also known as the **dotall** modifier which forces the dot `.` to also match newlines. The dotall modifier **does not** exist in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). The workaround is replacing the dot `.` with...

```
[\S\s]*
```

Your regular expression would look like this.

```
var regex = /-{2}Head([\S\s]*)-{2}\/Head/
```

Comment: [This answer is now obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll).