# Regex to match all the strings between two identical strings

Tags: javascript, regex

E.g. I have this string
`-- This -- is -- one -- another -- comment --`
I want the matched elements to be 
"This", "is", "one", "another", and "comment"

I was trying this regex
`--\s+([^--]+)\s+--`
which gives me the matched elements as
"This", "one" and "comment"

I have searched for other problems, they all provide solution like this i.e. `#A#` and I will get `A` but for `#A#B#` also I get `A`, but in this case I want both the elements `A` and `B` as both of them are between two `#` chars.

I am  testing it for javascript regex, but I think solution should be irrespective of platform/language.

Comment: Try this `--\s+([^--]+)\s+`, and then remove last two -- manually: http://www.regexr.com/3fffo

Comment: This `[^--]+` will prevent matching `mind-breaking` in `-- mind-breaking -- `

Comment: why not just \w+ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you need to use  a pattern like

```
STRING([\s\S]*?)(?=STRING|$)
```

It will match `STRING`, then capture into Group 1 any zero or more chars, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of `STRING` *stopping right before this word** because the `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead that, being a zero-width assertion, does not consume matched text or end of string.

A generic variation of the pattern is

```
STRING((?:(?!STRING)[\s\S])*)
```

It uses a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970), `(?:(?!STRING)[\s\S])*`, that matches any char, 0 or more occurrences, that does not start a `STRING` char sequence.

To get all the substrings in the current solution, use a lookahead like

```
/--\s+([\s\S]*?)(?=\s+--)/g
                ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vit67b/1).

Note that `[^--]+` matches 1 or more symbols other than a `-`, it does not match any text that is not equal to `--`. `[...]` is a character class that matches a *single* character. To match any text of any length from one char up to the first occurrence of a pattern, you can rely on a `[\s\S]*?` construct: any 0+ chars, as few as possible (due to the lazy `*?` quantifier).

JS demo:

```js
var s = '-- This -- is -- one -- another -- comment --';
var rx = /--\s+([\s\S]*?)(?=\s+--)/g;
var m, res=[];
while (m = rx.exec(s)) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Accepted the answer ! Thanks for solution with positive look ahead.

Comment: Lookarounds are the natural way to match substrings that overlap. Also, the `[\s\S]` that matches any char can be replaced with the native JS regex `[^]` construct (*not nothing*), but it is not portable. `[\s\S]` will work almost everywhere.

Comment: i wonder why you used `/--\s+([\s\S]*?)(?=\s+--)/g` instead of `/--\s+([\s\S]*?)\s+(?=--)/g` is there any performace reason or it's just aesthetics?

Comment: @MaciejKozieja: I do not think this is critical here, but that is interesting. Surely, the `\s+` can be moved outside the lookahead. If there is a real performance difference (the number of steps at regex101 does not actually prove any regex is better than another), a test in JS environment should be set up. See https://jsfiddle.net/pbL0cmsj/1/ - almost no difference in performance.

Comment: seams like [`/--\s+([\s\S]*?)(?=\s+--)/g` is faster](https://jsperf.com/regex-speed-comparison22)

Answer (score 0):

To read all I would use positive look ahead:

```js
const data = '-- This -- is -- one -- another -- comment --'

const readAll = data => {
  const regex =/--\s*(.*?)\s*(?=--)/g
  const found = []
  let temp
  while (temp = regex.exec(data)) {
    found.push(temp[1])
  }
  return found
}

console.log(readAll(data))
```

And to remove comments just do this:

```js
const data = `-- This -- is -- one -- another -- comment -- this is not a comment`.replace(/--.*--/g, '')

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Note that OP's `[^--]` matches line break chars, while your `.*?` will not.

Comment: If you want line break you can do (?:\n|.)*? because [^--] dont allow for usage of one - because it is not - character second dash means until

Comment: Maciek, never use `(?:\n|.)*?`. It will crash your browser one day. See my answer for a proper way to match any char with a JS regex.

Comment: So you use `[\s\S]` to get all characters including new lines etc thats clever   :D

Comment: See more about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36006948/3832970).