# Regex anything(including new lines) up to certain sequence - multiple substrings JS

Tags: javascript, regex

The File I am trying to process looks like this:

```
...
...
15 Apr 2014 22:05 - id: content
15 Apr 2014 22:09 - id: content
15 Apr 2014 22:09 - id: content
with new line
16 Apr 2014 06:56 - id: content
with new line
with new line
16 Apr 2014 06:57 - id: content

16 Apr 2014 06:58 - id: content
...
...
```

the regex I have come up with is this: `\d{1,}[ ][A-Z][a-z]{2}[ ](?:\d{4}[ ]\d{2}[:]\d{2}|\d{2}[:]\d{2}).*`

which results in:

[image]

This is almost right i just need to include newline characters, but if i include this `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*` only one match is returned.

[image]

What i would like to extract is a set of substrings where each string starts at the data sequence and ends at the next date sequence like so:

```
...
...
15 Apr 2014 22:05 - id: content //substring 1
15 Apr 2014 22:09 - id: content //substring 2
15 Apr 2014 22:09 - id: content //substring 3
with new line                   //substring 3
16 Apr 2014 06:56 - id: content //substring 4
with new line                   //substring 4
with new line                   //substring 4
16 Apr 2014 06:57 - id: content //substring 5

16 Apr 2014 06:58 - id: content //substring 6
...
...
```

Any help to what im missing?

Comment: If you're trying to get groups of dates and content, why use such a complicated regex, just splitting on two newlines to get groups, then on single newlines to get each line seems a lot easier ?

Comment: YES, but there could still be content on the next line that belongs to the previous one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a positive lookahead assertion.

```
\d{1,}[ ][A-Z][a-z]{2}[ ](?:\d{4}[ ]\d{2}[:]\d{2}|\d{2}[:]\d{2})[\s\S]*?(?:(?!\n\n)[\s\S])*?(?=\n\d{1,}[ ])|\d{1,}[ ][A-Z][a-z]{2}[ ](?:\d{4}[ ]\d{2}[:]\d{2}|\d{2}[:]\d{2}).*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wH0oM0/2)

```
> var str = '...\n...\n15 Apr 2014 22:05 - id: content\n15 Apr 2014 22:09 - id: content\n15 Apr 2014 22:09 - id: content\nwith new line\n16 Apr 2014 06:56 - id: content\nwith new line\nwith new line\n16 Apr 2014 06:57 - id: content\n\n16 Apr 2014 06:58 - id: content\n...\n...';
undefined
> var re = /\d{1,}[ ][A-Z][a-z]{2}[ ](?:\d{4}[ ]\d{2}[:]\d{2}|\d{2}[:]\d{2})[\s\S]*?(?:(?!\n\n)[\s\S])*?(?=\n\d{1,}[ ])|\d{1,}[ ][A-Z][a-z]{2}[ ](?:\d{4}[ ]\d{2}[:]\d{2}|\d{2}[:]\d{2}).*/gm;
undefined
> str.match(re)
[ '15 Apr 2014 22:05 - id: content',
  '15 Apr 2014 22:09 - id: content',
  '15 Apr 2014 22:09 - id: content\nwith new line',
  '16 Apr 2014 06:56 - id: content\nwith new line\nwith new line',
  '16 Apr 2014 06:57 - id: content\n',
  '16 Apr 2014 06:58 - id: content' ]
```

Comment: Thx, just a slight change: `(\d{1,}[ ][A-Z][a-z]{2}[ ](?:\d{4}[ ]\d{2}[:]\d{2}|\d{2}[:]\d{2})[\s\S]*?(?:(?!)[\s\S])*?(?=\d{1,}[ ])|\d{1,}[ ][A-Z][a-z]{2}[ ](?:\d{4}[ ]\d{2}[:]\d{2}|\d{2}[:]\d{2})[\s\S]*)`  Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cS7sB7/1

Answer (score -1):

See the second answer here: [How to use JavaScript regex over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines)

Try using the non-greedy quantifier [\s\S]? like that and see what it returns.
Alternatively, just get back one output and split the whole string on newlines afterwards...

Comment: its better to post the answer and add the link as reference. link content may be removed.