# regex extract last occurrence ignoring new line

Tags: javascript, regex

Considering a string like:

```
 "@foo #foo@foo@foo #foo\n
  foofoofoo\n 
  foo @bar"
```

I try for 2 days to extract the last `#/@` occurrence so here, the `@` before 'bar'. For now, i have something like this `[@#](?!.*[@#])` which seems to work except when user insert new lines in there.

Can someone give me  some tips please?

Comment: `.` does not match new line by default, do a catch all like `[\s\S]`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this lookhahead regex:

```
/[#@](?![\s\S]*[#@])/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS5qQ1/1)

`(?![\s\S]*[#@])` is the negative lookahead that asserts there is no `@` or `#` ahead of current position in any line. `[\s\S]` matches any character including newline.

Comment: Ty for your help but for a string like '@foo #bar' this regex gives me '@' when i expect '#'

Comment: `@foo #bar` will indeed match `#` [as you can see in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS5qQ1/2)

Comment: You were obvisouly right ty, helps me a lot !