# Regex to capture everything (incuding newlines) within a capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text (which some of you will recognize as part of a fortune file)

```
A day for firm decisions!!!!!  Or is it?
%
A few hours grace before the madness begins again.
%
A gift of a flower will soon be made to you.
%
A long-forgotten loved one will appear soon.

Buy the negatives at any price.
%
```

As can be seen, this contains both single line text and block text (as seen in the last fortune).

I currently have a regex that will capture all single line fortunes, however, it does not capture the multiline fortune.

`(?<=%\n)(.*?)(?=\n%)`

I understand that there is a `/m` multiline option, however, I do not want the entire regex to be multiline enabled (I have not gotten it to work at all in that way).

So my question is: How can I select multiline text blocks between delimiters as a local capture group? It should be noted that I will be using this in JavaScript.

Comment: What's your desire output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
str.split(/\n%\n/)
```

This splits the string by lines that contain `%` only.

Answer (score 0):

To match a newline, you can use `[^]` or `[\s\S]`. The dot does **not** match. This has nothing to do with the `m` flag, which has to do with whether anchors (`^` and `$`) match at the beginning and ends of lines. Other regexp engines have syntax for making the dot match newlines, and one is being proposed for a future version of JS, but for the time being you'll have to use one of the approaches above.

`[^]` literally means "match any character which is not nothing", which, as it turns out, includes a newline; `[\s\S]` literally means "match any character which is either whitespace or not whitespace", which also includes a newline.

Assuming your regexp currently works except for this newline problem, use

```
(?<=%\n)([^]*?)(?=\n%)
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines). There is some information on this in [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html). The TC39 proposal (for a new `s` flag) is [here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/es-regexp-dotall-flag).