# regexp for sql analysis

Tags: java, sql, regex

i`m trying find an regular expression for java that match all select statement queries that is not preceding by some keyword like insert,update,delete,procedure,etc:

At moment at got this:

```
^(?!insert|delete|update|procedure) {0,}select.*?;$ gims
```

but not matches right if select starts in new line :

Test cases:

```
select 1 from dual;
delete from table where id = 
(
select 1 from dual
);
update table set id = 1 where id in (
select 1 from dual);
procedure dsdsd select fdsfds;
PROCEDURE myproc ()
IS
BEGIN
SELECT
 1 from dual;
END myproc ;
```

Result : matches only `select 1 from dual;`

this link has test case :

https://regex101.com/r/2wkbOk/1

Comment: Sorry but i'dont understand what you means with (varying select statements).Can you give some examples ?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: only match select 1 from dual;

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/2wkbOk/1

Answer (score 0):

The "multiline" parameter considers each line independently, so the content on other lines is not considered in your current search. I believe what you're looking for is more of a search across lines in order to consider the statements on lines prior. Try a method utilizing [\s\S] instead of "."

Reference:
[How to use JavaScript regex over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines)

Comment: Im using this tool for easy debug https://regex101.com/r/2wkbOk/1 can you look at ?