# Javascript - Replace text beetwen special characters

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I'm trying to replace everything between special characters of a string in Javascript.

```
var text = "Hello,\n>> Someone lalalala\nMore Text\n<<";
```

I've tried the following code:

```
var newText = text.replace(/>>.*<</, ">>Some other text<<");
```

But at the end it actually returns the text variable.

I'd appreciate some thoughts about this. Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexes are "greedy", meaning they'll try to match the longest substring possible. Since `.*` means literally any character, it's going to include your delimiter `<<` as well. Thus, `.*` reaches all the way to the end of your string, and then it can't find `<<` after that, so the match will fail. You have to exclude it in your expression:

```
text.replace(/>>[^<]*<</, ">>Some other text<<");
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that '.' does not match new lines. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines#16119722):

```js
var text = "Hello,\n>> Someone lalalala\nMore Text\n<<";
var newText = text.replace(/>>[\s\S]*<</m, ">>Some other text<<");
console.log(newText);
```