# Javascript: replace until word is found

Tags: javascript

I have this string which consist of :

```
const string = `
/**
 * tests
 */
describe("tests", () => {
  it("create a role", async () => {});
});
`;
```

And i would like to delete the start of this string until the word `it(` is found. so i could have in the end something like this :

```
it("create a role", async () => {});
});
`
```

I tried working with this regex `string.replace(/^(.+?)(?=-it\(|$)/gi, "");` but still nothing works

Comment: What have you tried so far? A simple `while` loop that removes the first character until it starts with `it(` would do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/indexOf) to find the index of "it(" and then the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/slice) function

```js
const string = `
/**
 * tests
 */
describe("tests", () => {
  it("create a role", async () => {});
});
`;

const index = string.indexOf("it(");

console.log(string.slice(index))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the position and then cut the string:

```js
const str = `
/**
 * tests
 */
describe("tests", () => {
  it("create a role", async () => {});
});
`;

const res = str.substring(str.indexOf('it('));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @tiaranane You can accept the answer then to confirm your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

In RegExp you can use [`\[\s\S\]` to match anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16119722/3037257) (since `.` doesn't include newline character) and put your pattern within the [look-ahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) since we don't want to remove the pattern(`it(`).

```
string.replace(/^[\s\S]*(?=it\()/, '')
```

```js
const string = `
/**
 * tests
 */
describe("tests", () => {
  it("create a role", async () => {});
});
`;

console.log(string.replace(/^[\s\S]*(?=it\()/, ''));
```