# regex , match including multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I my regex doesnt work if there is multiple lines.I'm  trying to match that everything inside /#----- #/ symbols. In one single line it works fine. You can check it here: https://regex101.com/r/yZTXwh/3

code:

```
highlightMessage(message) {
    return message.replace(
      /\/#\s*(.*?)\s*#\//g,
      (_, g) => `<span class='highlited-message'>${g}</span>`,
    )
  }
```

text:

```
Hello
 /# my name
is
Mike
nice to meet you

 #/
```

Comment: Use `[\w\W]` as `.` by default doesn't match newline

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript regex over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 0):

You could use  [^]* to match any thing include a newline

please try this:

```
function highlightMessage(message) {
    return message.replace(
      /\/#\s*([^]*)\s*#\//g,
      (_, g) => `<span class='highlited-message'>${g}</span>`,
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to match the `/#...#/` block's significant characters:

`/\/#\s*((?:.|\n)*?)\s*#\//gm`

```js
let s = `Hello
 /# my name
is
Mike
nice to meet you

 #/ 
 bar
 /# single-line #/
 foo
 /#
 
 multi-line
 
 #/
 baz
 `;
 
 let r = /\/#\s*((?:.|\n)*?)\s*#\//gm;
 let a;
 while ((a = r.exec(s)) !== null)
   console.log(a[1]);
```

Here's a [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WAjbh4/3)