# Regex - match string with special characters between delimiter (html <style> tag)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a solution to match html style tags with arbitrary text (also special chars) inbetween in API response which contains a proper html template:

Part of the string:

```
...
Aenean <style>asdfasdf</style>lacinia bibendum <a href="/life">life</a> 
sed <style>asdfasdf</style>consectetur. 
<a href="/work">Work</a> quis risus eget urna mollis ornare 
<a href="/about">about</a> <!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]-->leo.
...
```

My regex (so far):
`<style[^>]*>(.*?)<\/style>`

matches just the style tags with no special characters
`<style>asdfasdf</style>`
but still missing out on

```
<style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style>
```

To test:
https://regexr.com/ - regex expression and text as described above.

---

Complete working JavaScript sequence to directly copy paste into your code:

```
console.warn(value);
console.warn(/<style[^>]*>(.*?)<\/style>/gs.test(value));
value = value.replace(/<style[^>]*>(.*?)<\/style>/gs, '');
console.warn(value);
console.warn(/<style[^>]*>(.*?)<\/style>/gs.test(value));
```

Returns:
string
true
string
false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript regex over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines)

Comment: Basically `.` stops when you hit a newline.

Comment: `<style[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/style>`, but you'd probably better parse the text as HTML and use dom traversing

Comment: The text is a value for an [innerHTLM] directive later on. My problem is that I'm querying an catch all emailbox and if the email contains HTML I want to remove the included styling first. tldr: it gets parsed later on anyway. ([^<]*) didn't find a match at all anymore.

Comment: @MattEllen While the title of that proposed duplicate looks relevant, the accepted answer there certainly wouldn't help OP

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ true, but the most upvoted answer does help.

Comment: Most likely it is a duplicate or similar to a past question but not to one of the mentioned questions, as the problem is not the multiple lines but matching a string over "span line boundaries".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `s` regex flag which allows matches to span line boundaries:

Something like 
`(?s)<style[^>]*>(.*?)<\/style>`, try it [here](https://regexr.com/4dmao).
(`/<style[^>]*>(.*?)<\/style>/gs` in JS syntax)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I edited the answer and added the working JavaScript sequence which hopefully helps others with the same problem later on.

Comment: I've implemented the solution mentioned above. It worked like a charm in Chrome but after testing it with different browsers I figured out FF is not able to handle the /s regex flag. Any experience with this issue? "SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag s"

Comment: /s regex flag was implemented with ES9/ES2018 and is for now only implemented in Chrome: https://flaviocopes.com/es2018/

Comment: @hiimvinzent Are you transpiling your JS? It is likely that `/s` has a corresponding transform, for example here is the one for Babel: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-dotall-regex

Comment: Moved the stripping with regex to a backend layer for now. Looks like a proper approach but I didn't try it yet.