# Regex everything between quotation marks, including line breaks

Tags: python, regex

I stumbled across a problem trying to perform a regex that captures everything between two quotation marks `""`. I noticed that sometimes there is a line break that occurs in between these quotation marks which breaks the regex.

Current regex that I am using:  `\"((?:(?![(]).)*)\"`

This does a great job of capturing everything between quotation marks except if a line break occurs.

Any regex gurus know how to also allow for line breaks, this pattern has me stumped.

Comment: ..or simply `flags=re.DOTALL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript regex over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines)

Comment: Looks like your regex is matching a quoted string but skipping a match if `(` is anywhere inside quoted string. Is that how you wanted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you use simply:

```
\"([^\"]*)\"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q1HsXU/1/)

Eg.

```
re.search(r'\"([^\"]*)\"', "\"a\nb\"").groups()
# Out[19]: ('a\nb',)
```