# Create a regex to replace the last occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I need to create a regex which should look for the last '*' irrespective of the whitespace in the string.
Then, I need to replace that string with some text.

Currently, it is replacing the first occurence of '*' in the string.

How do I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
const regex = /\*/m;
const str = 'Field Name* * ';
const replaceStr = ' mandatory';
const result = str.replace(regex, replaceStr);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Here, the output should be 'Field Name* mandatory'. But what I get is 'Field Name mandatory *'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of RegEx, use [`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`String.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) as below

```js
const str = 'Field Name* * ';
const replaceStr = 'mandatory';
const lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf('*');
const result = str.substring(0, lastIndex) + replaceStr + str.substring(lastIndex + 1);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

[**Still want to use RegEx?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58988070/create-a-regex-to-replace-the-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string#comment104227954_58988099)

```js
const regex = /\*([^*]*)$/;
const str = 'Field Name* * Hello World!';
const replaceStr = ' mandatory';
const result = str.replace(regex, (m, $1) => replaceStr + $1);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, but I need to use regex here.

Comment: @Sunny Added regex.

Comment: @Sunny BTW, why do you want RegEx only solution?

Comment: We are using regex everywhere in the project for any replacements. Hence, need to use it here as well.

Comment: @Sunny I'll suggest to use String replacement wherever possible, it'll be faster than RegEx replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Short *regex* magic (shown on extended input `str`):

```js
const regex = /\*(?=[^*]*$)/m,
      str = 'Field Name* * * * ',
      replaceStr = ' mandatory',
      result = str.replace(regex, replaceStr);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

- `(?=[^*]*$)` - lookahead positive assertion, ensures that the former `\*` is matched only if it's followed by `[^*]*` (non-asterisk char right up to the end of the string `$`)

Answer (score 1):

Just let [`.*`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) [consume](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) before last `*` and [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) it. Replace with [captured `$1`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `mandatory`.

```js
let str = 'Field Name* * ';
let res = str.replace(/(.*)\*/,'$1mandatory');
console.log(res);
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xbkGOF/1)

- If you have `Field Name* *abc` and want to strip out end as well, use [`(.*)\*.*`](https://regex101.com/r/Jm2GTW/5)
- If you have multline input, use [`[\S\s]*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines) instead of `.*` to skip over newlines