# Regex, Replace brackets between two substrings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not great with Regex and I am trying to replace two characters in a set string.

I need this:

```
This is some variable text
<foo> some stuff <Hello World> other stuff <bar>
```

To be replaced with this:

```
This is some variable text
<foo> some stuff (Hello World) other stuff <bar>
```

Edit: In this example I want to find all `<` and `>`, to replace them with `(` and `)` respectively between `<foo>` and `<bar>` in the larger string.

Comment: What makes `Hello World` special? Why shouldn't `foo` and `bar` also be replaced?

Comment: Hello world is not special, foo and bar are special because I would like to only target the "<" and ">" in between those tags. Hello world must simply stay the same.

Comment: Please always add environment/tool you're using and what regex you already wrote but did not work. If this is for JS, have a try with something [like this demo](https://tio.run/##lY2xDoIwEEB3vuIGE1qpIDgCdfUPXKlwgKblSFv9/dpgjLPLDXfv3Xuol3K9va/@sNCAIWj04LyFFrpmJJLgyGDcPMcRmgtqTXAlqwcJ5Ge038tNWQn/Cl2dJJ9WnLnFVaseWcG2P5zl@zNnG8iLSQAzR2FKYSphThxaCabMTPXTmk2QEU3ZruQpzyIXCz0tjjTmmiYWO7wO4Q0).

Comment: @bobblebubble Thank you! My apologies for not specifying the environment, but your demo solves my problem!

Comment: @TylerLawson You're welcome glad it helped :) I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using two replaces. One for [`(<foo>)(.*?)(<bar>)`](https://regex101.com/r/P8qLEq/1) and on [what was captured](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference) by the second [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) a callback function that replaces [`<(.*?)>` with `($1)`](https://regex101.com/r/P8qLEq/2)

```
s = s.replace(/(<foo>)(.*?)(<bar>)/g, (m0,m1,m2,m3) => m1+m2.replace(/<(.*?)>/g,'($1)')+m3);
```

[See this JS demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##lY0xEoIwEEV7T7GFM2wkgmAJxNYb2BJhQZ2EZZLo9SMy41hb//fef@iX9p27z2E/cU8xGgrgoYG2HpgVeLYEPjyHAeozGcNwYWd6BRxu5L7LVTsF/wpttdl8nnzmaDa6I8xxbQjMdieBKyTyUQLag7SFtKW0RwGNAluktvxp9SqoBU1wW4hEpAu31DuePBvKDI/oRRXjGw)

For multiline strings use `([\s\S]*?)` instead of `(.*?)` to skip over newlines ([the dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16119722/5527985)).

Comment: Hi @bobblebubble I have another project I need this same problem solved written in ASP.NET. Is it possible to get this same solution done with .NET/C# ?

Comment: @TylerLawson Probably you can do this in .NET in a similar way. Something [like this demo](https://tio.run/##XZA/T8MwEMXn@FOcIoYYSqTCmBCGCsFAF4joUBgc99JYOHHkc6qgqp89OOkfISwvfvfe0@8s6VYai8PQkWq28P5DDuuE/X3FOfYufsNtp4V96luLRMo0lDAmtSCCHMmxPQvICack7IzawFKoJuIs8HKwExYIHiDMK0XgL5kawatKFBrB@frPJi2NyY4Tcl1ZQvqCWhtYGas3GRhXoT1PCmGzMPHNY6sHw97jtVpIjGgGYTR18Si@fuTRZObhDBZC60LIbz4GF57faIxXVjl8VY0PjvqBXbYgZ8cvOKeipXCygprDnoE/QWDRdbaBOn62pmtpPf@KP4TuEG7@IV0cdyeHR0wnuCwcaa/mPOQ@dfHdn3xHoMMw/AI). I have no experience in .NET, you might just want to ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command with the regex as follows:

```
perl -pe 's/(<foo>.*)<(.*)>(.*<bar>)/$1($2)$3/'
```

Comment: Try it with `<foo> blah <Hello> blah <bar> blah <foo> blah <World> <bar>`. Moreover this question is about javascript, not Perl.

Comment: When I wrote my answer, there was no specific language tagged or mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(`This is some variable text
<foo> some stuff <Hello World> other stuff <bar>`
.replace(/<\w+>|([<>])/g, (m, c) => ({'<':'(', '>':')'}[c] || m)))
```

Comment: This will do the replacement even outside `<foo>...<bar>`

Comment: @Toto, you are right, but the answer was posted for [original version of question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59383531/1).

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(`This is some variable text
<foo> some stuff <Hello World> other stuff <bar>`
.replace(/<(?!\w+>)/g, "(")
.replace(/>(?<!<\w+>)/g, ")")
)
```

Comment: Lookbehind doesn't works in all browsers, with Firefox I get `"message": "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group",`. This will do the replacement even outside `<foo>...<bar>`

Comment: The answer was posted for [original version of question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59383531/1).

Comment: @Toto, there was no [tag:javascript] tag on the question. By the way, this tag is added by other user. I expect asker to know which regex engine he uses and what features are supported by it.