# Regex pattern to match the java part in JSP code

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match the content between <%.....%> in a JSP code.
Suppose the sample JSP code is :

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Auto Refresh</title>
    </head>
    <body>
                <fieldset style="width:20%; background-color:#e6ffe6;">
                    <legend>Auto refresh</legend>
                    <h2>Auto Refresh Example</h2>
                    <%
                       // Set refresh, autoload time as 1 seconds
                       response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 1);
                       // Get current time
                       Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                       String am_pm;
                       int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                       int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                       int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                       if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
                          am_pm = "AM";
                       else
                          am_pm = "PM";
                       String CT = hour+":"+ minute +":"+ second +" "+ am_pm;
                       out.println("Crrent Time: " + CT + "\n");
                    %>
                </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

My regex is `/\<\%[\w \@\=\.\*\,\"\$\#\!\&\(\)\/\/\n\+\;\:]*\%\>/gi`
Its only matching the first part i.e

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
```

Not the second part

```
                    <%
                       // Set refresh, autoload time as 1 seconds
                       response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 1);
                      ........
                       String CT = hour+":"+ minute +":"+ second +" "+ am_pm;
                       out.println("Crrent Time: " + CT + "\n");
                    %>
```

Comment: How about just using something like [`<%[\s\S]*?%>`](https://regex101.com/r/5FMBM4/1)

Comment: It's matching the <html>...........<h2>Auto Refresh Example</h2> part also then

Comment: Have you tried [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/5FMBM4/1)? I don't see it matches that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drop `%>` for trial you can [see how far it matches](https://regex101.com/r/XYvxDE/1). Until the backslash at `\n"` because it's not included in your specified characterset. Add the backslash or use something more general like

```
/<%[\s\S]*?%>/g
```

which will lazily match any amount of [any character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines) in between `<%` and `%>`.

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5FMBM4/1)

Comment: is there any way to have not operation in regex i.e suppose if i want to match all the text except the ones this regex match .

Comment: @souv202112 You could try [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/CAdGmc/1)  which captures the other stuff to group 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex. It's short and simple.

```
/<%.*?%>/gs
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H0tIsz/1)

**Explanation**

`.*?` matches any character from zero to unlimited times, as few times as possible (lazy).

So, it takes everything between `<%` and closest `%>`. Pay attention to single line modifier `/s`