# Want correct Regex to extract a text from responsetext from server and do JSON.parse on extracted text

Tags: json, regex, web-scraping, puppeteer

```
await page.on("response", async (response) => {
        const request = await response.request();
        if (
          request.url().includes("https://www.jobs.abbott/us/en/search-results")
        ) {
          const text = await response.text();
          const root = await parse(text);
          root.querySelectorAll("script").map(async function (n) {
            if (n.rawText.includes("eagerLoadRefineSearch")) {
             const text = await n.rawText.match(
                 /"eagerLoadRefineSearch":(\{.*\})\,/,
               );
               const refinedtext = await text[0].match(/\[{.*}\]/);
              //console.log(refinedtext);
              console.log(JSON.parse(refinedtext[0]));
               }
          });
        }
      });
```

In the snippet I have posted a data which is in text format I want to extract `eagerLoadRefineSearch : { (and its content too)}` as a text with `regex` and perform `json.parse` on extracted text so that i get finally a json object of `"eagerLoadRefineSearch" : {}`.

I am using `puppetter` for intercepting response. I just want a correct `regex` which can get me whole object text of `"eagerLoadRefineSearch" : {}` (with its content).

I am sharing the response text from the server in this link https://codeshare.io/bvjzJA .

I want to extract `"eagerLoadRefineSearch" : {}` from the data which is in text format in this https://codeshare.io/bvjzJA

Comment: I don't know if `regex` can get it. It needs to count `{` and `}` - it needs the same number of `{` and `}`

Comment: But I guess regex can match a pattern where we allow any nested objects, like "eagerLoadRefineSearch" : { "jobs" : [ ],status : 200,hits:500}  this object. this  /"eagerLoadRefineSearch":(\{.*\})\,/ regex is also getting other text which is next to eagerLoadRefineSearch. But it is starting at correct point

Answer (score 2):

## Context

### Silly mistakes

The text you are parsing has no flanked `"` around `eagerLoadRefineSearch`. Now the object to match spans across several lines thus `m` flag is required. Also `.` does not match new line so the alternative is to use `[\s\S]`. Refer to [how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines).

Also also, don't use `await` on string method `match`.

### Matching the closing brace

Quick search on this topic lead me to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses) and as I suspected, this is complicated. To ease this problem I made this assumption that the text is correctly indented. We can match on the indentation level to find the closing brace with this pattern.

```js
/(?<indent>[\s]+)\{[\s\S]+\k<indent>\}/gm
```

This works if the both the opening and the closing braces are at the same level of indentation. They are not in our case since `eagerLoadRefineSearch:`  is between the indent and opening brace but we can account for this.

```js
const reMatchObject = /(?<indent>[\s]+)eagerLoadRefineSearch: \{[\s\S]+?\k<indent>\}/gm
```

### Valid JSON

As metioned earlier the keys lack flanking double quotes so lets replace all `key`s with `"key"`s.

```js
const reMatchKeys = /(\w+):/gm
const impure = 'hello: { name: "nammu", age: 18, subjects: { first: "english", second: "mythology"}}'
const pure = impure.replace(reMatchKeys, '"$1":')
console.log(pure)
```

Then we get rid of the trailing commas. Here's the regex that worked for **this** example.

```js
const reMatchTrailingCommas = /,(?=\s+[\]\}])/gm
```

Once we pipe these `replace` functions, the data is good to use by `JSON.parse`.

## Code

```js
await page.on('response', async (response) => {
  const request = await response.request();
  if (
    request
      .url()
      .includes('https://www.jobs.abbott/us/en/search-results')
  ) {
    const text = await response.text();
    const root = await parse(text);
    root.querySelectorAll('script').map(async function (n) {
      const data = n.rawText;
      if (data.includes('eagerLoadRefineSearch')) {
        const reMatchObject = /(?<indent>[\s]+)eagerLoadRefineSearch: \{[\s\S]+?\k<indent>\}/gm;
        const reMatchKeys = /(\w+):\s/g;
        const reMatchTrailingCommas = /,(?=\s+[\]\}])/gm;
        const parsedStringArray = data.toString().match(reMatchObject);
        for (const parsed of parsedStringArray) {
          const noTrailingCommas = parsed.replace(reMatchTrailingCommas, '');
          const validJSONString = '{' + noTrailingCommas.replace(reMatchKeys, '"$1":') + '}';
          console.log(JSON.parse(validJSONString));
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```