# JS: matching entries with capture groups, accounting for new lines

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this text:

```
1/12/2011
I did something.

10/5/2013
I did something else.

Here is another line.

And another.

5/17/2014
Lalala.
More text on another line.
```

I would like to use regex (or maybe some other means?) to get this:

```
["1/12/2011", "I did something.", "10/5/2013", "I did something else.\n\nHere is another line.\n\nAnd another.", "5/17/2014", "Lalala.\nMore text on another line."]
```

The **date part** and **content part** are each separate entries, alternating.

I've tried using [^] instead of the dot since JS's .* does not match new lines (as [Matching multiline Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387116/matching-multiline-patterns) says), but then the match is greedy and takes up too much, so the resulting array only has 1 entry:

```
var split_pattern = /\b(\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d)\n([^]+)/gm;
var array_of_mems = contents.match(split_pattern);

// => ["1/12/2011↵I did something else..."]
```

If I add a question mark to get [^]+?, which according to [How to make Regular expression into non-greedy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824302/how-to-make-regular-expression-into-non-greedy) makes the match non-greedy, then I only get the first character of the content part.

What's the best method? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `exec()` method in a loop to get your desired results.

```
var re  = /^([\d/]+)\s*((?:(?!\s*^[\d/]+)[\S\s])+)/gm, 
matches = [];

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  matches.push(m[1]);
  matches.push(m[2]);
}
```

**Output**

```
[ '1/12/2011',
  'I did something.',
  '10/5/2013',
  'I did something else.\n\nHere is another line.\n\nAnd another.',
  '5/17/2014',
  'Lalala.\nMore text on another line.' ]
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/314745)

Comment: Could I get some explanation on the regex - how does the [\d/]+ work? And it seems a key idea is to use [\S\s]... what is this exactly? Or just key points about the regex in general, since I would like to understand it instead of just plainly copying it.

I will look into the ?: and ?! - non-capturing grouop & negative lookahead I think... those are key ideas I wasn't considering when trying to write my own regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})\n|((?:(?!\n*\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})[\s\S])+)
```

You can try this.grab the captures.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/126

```
var re = /(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})\n|((?:(?!\n*\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})[\s\S])+)/gim;
var str = '1/12/2011\nI did something.\n\n10/5/2013\nI did something else.\n\nHere is another line.\n\nAnd another.\n\n5/17/2014\nLalala.\nMore text on another line.';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!
Does the "?:" apply to "(?!\n*\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})" only, or does it apply to "((?!\n*\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})[\s\S])+" ? The syntax tells me the latter, but then I don't understand how the content like "I did something" gets matched, because "?:" means to not capture the match.