# How to match space, newline in regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

String content

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <!--@require a.css-->
    <!--@require BOWER/jquery-->
    <!--@require /build/bundle-->
    <!--
        @require bootstrap
        @require bootstrap.css
        @require bootstrap.font
    -->
</head>
```

JS

```
var content = ...;
var reg = /<!--[\s\t\n]*?@require (.+?)[\s\t\n]*?-->/g;
var r;
while((r = reg.exec(content)) != null) {
  console.log(r[1]);
}
```

Output

```
a.css
BOWER/jquery
/build/bundle
```

It's not match the last block, what miss in my reg expression.

Comment: `\s` matches any kind of whitespaces including newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Dot). Matches any character except newline , that's why the last string is not matching. So you can use something like `[\s\S]*` or `[^]` for matching any character. ( Ref : [Matching multiline Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387116/matching-multiline-patterns) )

```js
var content = `<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <!--@require a.css-->
    <!--@require BOWER/jquery-->
    <!--@require /build/bundle-->
    <!--
        @require bootstrap
        @require bootstrap.css
        @require bootstrap.font
    -->
</head>`;
var reg = /<!--[\s\t\n]*?@require ([\s\S]+?)[\s\t\n]*?-->/g;
var r;
while ((r = reg.exec(content)) != null) {
  console.log(r[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **multiline flag** (`m`)

```
/<!--[\s\t\n]*?@require ([\s\S]+?)[\s\t\n]*?-->/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@require (.+?)?(?:-->|\s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eA3zQ0/1)

**Explanation:**
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`.`: Any character except line break [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wY6xS4/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`(?: … )`: Non-capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bU9dN1/1)
`|`: Alternation / OR operand [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ0iC0/1)
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [71-76] `a.css`
MATCH 2
1.  [97-109]    `BOWER/jquery`
MATCH 3
1.  [130-143]   `/build/bundle`
MATCH 4
1.  [173-182]   `bootstrap`
MATCH 5
1.  [200-213]   `bootstrap.css`
MATCH 6
1.  [231-245]   `bootstrap.font`
```